# Creating Test cases using Decision Table Method

Tags: testing, testcase, black-box-testing

19. Assume you are a test analyst working on a banking project to upgrade an existing automated teller machine system to allow customers to obtain cash advances from supported credit cards. The system should allow cash advances from 20 dollars to 500 dollars, inclusively, for all supported credit cards. The correct list of supported credit cards is American Express, Visa, Japan Credit Bank, Eurocard, and MasterCard. The user interface starts with a default amount of 100 dollars for advances, and the ATM keypad is used to increase or decrease that amount in 20-dollar increments.
    Consider the decision table shown in table 1.0 that describes the handling of these transactions.
    Table 1.0. Cash advance decision table
    [Check the table in attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lECVy.png)

Assume that you want to design a set of test cases where the following coverage is achieved:
Decision table coverage
Boundary values for allowed and disallowed advance amounts
Successful advance for each supported card
Design a set of test cases that achieves this level of coverage with the minimum possible number of test cases. Assume each test case consists of a single combination of conditions to create and a single combination of actions to check. How many test cases do you need?

Can someone help me understanding this problem and solution?

Thanks in Advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Decision table coverage Boundary values for allowed and disallowed advance amounts ->
   Boundary values for your example will be: less than 0; 0; 20-500; 500+.
   Equivalence partitioning, boundary value testing and decision table described  here: http://www.maniuk.net/search/label/test%20design%20technique
2. Successful advance for each supported card -> 
   Set of instruction number 5 (in decision table) should be applied for all types of provided cars. Depends on risks #4 should be tested too.
3. Design a set of test cases that achieves this level of coverage with the minimum possible number of test cases. -->
   a. If we can assume that cards work totally the same with the same limits and processing procedures so 9 test cases needed, during boundaries testing you can use different cards, so each card can be used. b. If we assume that some specific still exists in processing so 13 test cases needed (9 from previous test + 4 other cards to test instruction #5.
   c. If cards has different limits by themselves addition verification will be needed.